# How do I fix "System.String[]" Error in C# ? (using arrays + For loop)

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, for-loop

Okay so, I'm trying to make a program that basically uses a for loop to display the days of the week, my code seems fine, runs fine, but when I happen to run it.. it comes up "The day of the week is System.String[]".. Whereas I want it to display The day of the week is Monday... The day of the week is Tuesday... Wednesday.. Etc.

Here is the code I have written for this so far:

```
        //Declare variables
        int iDays;

        //Declare array
        const int iWEEK = 7;
        string[] sDays = new string[iWEEK] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };

        //Display the days of the week
        for (iDays = 0; iDays < iWEEK; iDays++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The day of the week is " + sDays);
        }

        //Prevent program from closing
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to print a value inside the array, not the array itself.

use `sDays[iDays]` instead. This will retrieve the value at location `iDays` in the array `sDays`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried pretty much everything other than this.. I feel rather dumb now, I was trying sDays[iWEEK] which came up a bad error too, thanks tho!

Comment: We've all been there, no problem. You had an error with `sDays[iWEEK]` because that would try to access index 7. Your array only has indices 0 to 6.

Comment: `sDays[iWEEK]` would give you `Index was outside the bounds of the array.` because you would supply it with `7` which is a higher index than what exists in your array. Arrays start at index `0` so `6` would be the highest index you could use, it's still the 7th value though!

Comment: Ah okay, Yeah I understand that now, Thank you for your help, appreciated :)

Comment: @zespri yeah don't worry, have every intention on doing so, just says I need to wait 6 minutes before I can do so

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely don't need array to display weekdays' names. They are already present in system:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 7; i++)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
    dt = dt.AddDays(i - (int)DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek);
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("dddd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//Declare variables
        int iDays;

```
    //Declare array
    const int iWEEK = 7;
    string[] sDays = new string[iWEEK] { "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday" };

    //Display the days of the week
    for (iDays = 0; iDays < iWEEK; iDays++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The day of the week is " + sDays[iDays]);
    }

    //Prevent program from closing
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
    Console.ReadKey();
```